# How can i debug why a dialog will open in web outlook but not in 2016?

Tags: typescript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

My dialog will open correctly in the office web app but in office 2016 it only shows a loading indicator and says `working on your request`. I've tried adding a task pane which works and I use that first to ensure I accept the https certificate override but still no luck. No dialog attempts to appear and I just see an inline indicator.

There doesn't seem to be any office developer console I can open to help debug what is going on.

my functions html file looks like this

```
function showSmsModal() {
  Office.context.ui
    .displayDialogAsync("https://localhost:3000/send-sms", { height: 30, width: 20 });
}

(() => {
  // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
  Office.initialize = () => {
    console.log("inited");
  };

  // Add any ui-less function here
})();
```

while the index file that the dialog html is plane html with a react root and the js file looks like this.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


if (!!Office) {
  Office.initialize = async () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<div>test</div>, document.getElementById('root'))
  }
}
```

and finally the relevant manifest xml

```xml
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
    <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
    <Supertip>
        <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
        <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
    </Supertip>
    <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
    </Icon>
    <!-- <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
            <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
         </Action> -->
    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
        <FunctionName>showSmsModal</FunctionName>
    </Action>
</Control>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a callback to see what (if any) errors are being returned? See https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync

Comment: I've taken a look at that but I'm still stuck in that I cannot lot the error / success result into the window so i'm still at square 1 as far as i can tell

Comment: scratch that. I've decided to make my handler `(...res) => Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(JSON.stringify(res))` which works in browsers but does nothing in the office application

Comment: Keep in mind that for Office for Windows (desktop), it is using embedded IE11. You may need to polyfill in order to support some ES2015 functions.

Comment: that is it. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch the "F12 Developer Tools" as a separate instance to debug an add-in in Office 2016 for Windows. The process is outlined here: [Debug add-ins using F12 developer tools on Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10).

**Important: The referenced documentation has an error. The executable is `IEChooser.exe` *not* `F12Chooser.exe`. Otherwise, the documentation is accurate.**

Comment: i'll check this out and likely mark it as my answer tomorrow. Thanks for your help!